# How to legally run a Windows VM without purchasing a license now Windows XP Mode is removed?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-xp-mode

For work, I VPN to their network and then launch an RDP session. To sandbox the VPN session, I use XP Mode on my Windows 7 PC simply because it was free and very easy to set up when I was setting the PC up.

As I prepare to move to Windows 10, are there options to legally replicate this setup without having to buy another license? The VM on my desktop will *only* be used to run the VPN client and RDP, nothing else at all. So really, a complete VM is a bit overkill but the VPN *must* be sandboxed.

Do MS provide tools out of the box, or do I need a 3rd-party product like VirtualBox?

I suppose an alternative title would be **Does MS provide any replacement for XP Mode in Windows 8 and 10?** I am not really asking into deep licensing issues, just asking if a simple and well-recognised alternative exists. I do *not* wish to continue using XP, that was just convenient at the time.

Comment: Have a look here man --> [XP Mode](http://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-add-an-XP-Mode-Virtual-Machine-to-Windows-10-or-8-using-Hyper-V-00770). Maybe this will be a good pointer for you.  Otherwise, I know VirtualBox works good. I cannot speak to legalities though; but XP has ended support so. . .

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12309/install-xp-mode-with-virtualbox-using-the-vmlite-plugin/ You can follow this tutorial to move your XP Mode to VirtualBox (and to Windows 10 after that). But I don't think it's a legal practice because EULA says you must be using Win 7 Ultimate, Pro or Enterprise to run XP Mode legally.

Comment: The Windows XP license included for XP Mode, is valid for that Windows 7 install only.  If you want to keep using Windows (XP or otherwise) in a VM in Windows 8+, you need to buy a licence for it. VTC as off-topic (we're not lawyers).  For the technical side of your question, it's too broad.  Windows 10 provides Hyper-V, and VBox or VMware will also work fine.  If you want a cheap/free alternative, just install a hypervisor and use Linux in you VM for VPN+RDP.

Comment: Licensing is a pretty big part of using software. Whether MS allow you to run a VM on your home PC doesn't sound like a particularly complicated question - I wondered if they provide this in W10. If they don't, "you need to investigate licensing" is a valid answer

Answer (score 1):

XP Mode was a Windows 7 "one-time bonus", and there has been no replacement for it provided by MS since Windows 8. From [Install and use Windows XP Mode in Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) (**highlight** mine):

> Using Windows XP Mode, you can run programs that were designed for Windows XP on computers running Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate editions. **Windows XP Mode isn't supported on Windows 8**.

About Windows 10 in particular, from the semi-official [Frequently Asked Questions: Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9):

> Which features will be removed when I upgrade from a previous version of Windows?
>
> - [...] Windows Virtual PC with Windows XP Mode

It's still possible to run XP virtual machines under Windows 10, but they would need their own license and activation, just as if you had XP on a separate physical machine.